# How to disable auto save method in libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, autosave

Currently I'm working in libreoffice with large amount of data . while working in libreoffice it automatically save and this save taking so much time so how to disable auto save method in libreoffice .I'll save the hole document by end of the finishing work please tell me how to do this.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [SuperUser SE](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to configure the below steps so your problem gets solved.

1. Open Tools->Options dialog box,
2. Open Load/Save, then choose General,
3. Adjust "Save AutoRecovery information" to whatever you want. Maybe you have "Automatically save the document too" checked?
4. If yes try to uncheck this first.

I hope this should help solve your problem.

Regards,
Sudhir

Comment: Thanq for great full information